# Calling web services in stack in android

Tags: android, web-services

Hi i am developing android application. I am calling web services to get the data from the Server. Now on one activity i am calling around 15 - 20 web services on onCreate method. Now i want to code it in such a way that after the response of 1st Service is received then only the other web service call. But i don't know how to maintain it. Any help or suggestions are appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simple...

you have to use AsyncTask class.

1. extend this class
2. override the following methods
   (i) doinBackground (this method will run when you first start the AsyncTask)
   (ii) onPostExecute (When doInBackgroun completed its work, this method starts executing)
3. run the Async class.

explanation:
you just do your web service calling in doInBackground and execute another AsyncTask ,which has another service call in its doinBackground, in onPostExecute.

summary: execute AsyncTrask class from onPostExecute and call webservice in doInBackground.

here i am giving you some code snippet:

```
 class ExecuteRest1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Call your first web service here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        new ExecuteRest2.execute();
    }
  }

 class ExecuteRest2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Call your second web service here
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        new ExecuteRest3.execute();
    }
  }

//And so on....
```

in onCreate():

```
new ExecuteRest1.execute();
```

Comment: Siraj:Thanxs for the suggestion. Now my question is i am calling 3 web services in for loop. So that how to execute the ExecuteRest1 class?? Do i have to perform it in for loop?

Comment: you cannot execute a single refrence more than once so if you want to execute ExecuteRest1 class more than once you have to create its ref in for loop e.g: in loop{myRef = new ExecuteRest1(); myRef.execute();}